# Unknown number of pushpins on Bing Maps Windows Phone. How do I create an event for each of them?

Tags: c#, windows, events, dictionary, bing

I'm currently working on an app for a Windows Phone. It works with Bing Maps, and I have multiple pins with different stored properties placed on the map.

I want to be able to tap on any of the pins, and open a new page displaying the pins properties.

Pins can be added and removed by the user, so there is an unknown number of them.  So, what is the best way to create the tap events? Is there a way to dynamically create C# code? Or, should I create some form of 'if' function that checks every time the screen is tapped whether there is a pin in that location?

Answer (score 0):

```
I understand your problem. You want to click on pushpin and on that click event, you want to open a new page. Write the above code in PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(). Here is the code..

private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
map1.Center = new GeoCoordinate(21.7679, 78.8718); //coordinates for location of India
map1.ZoomLevel = 5;

Pushpin puspin1 = new Pushpin();
puspin1.Location = new GeoCoordinate(21.7679, 78.8718);
puspin1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
puspin1.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(puspin1_MouseLeftButtonUp);
map1.Children.Add(puspin1);

}

void puspin1_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("YourWindowName", UriKind.Relative));
}
```